# simple bind failed exception when calling JNDI code from AWS lambda

Tags: ssl, aws-lambda, active-directory

I have lambda code that calls JNDI APIs to perform LDAP operations in AD. Communication to AD should be on LDAPS. Any suggestions how to connect to AD via LDAPS in lambda?

```
javax.naming.CommunicationException: simple bind failed: adhost1.example.com:636 
[Root exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: 
PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: 
unable to find valid certification path to requested target]
```